# Harmonic and geometric mean convergence to $L$ $\Rightarrow$ the series converges to $L$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, means

Given that the series $a_n > 0$, and its Harmonic mean and Geometric mean converges to L, does this indecate that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$ ?

> given $a_n$, the Harmonic mean is defined as :
>   $$
> \frac{n}{a_1^{-1}+a_2^{-1}+\ldots+a_n^{-1}}
> $$
>   and the Geometric mean is defined as : 
>   $$
> \sqrt[n]{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider for example the sequence
$\;\displaystyle 
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{if } n = 2^k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{N} \\[5px]
1 \quad \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

The harmonic and geometric means both converge to $\,L=1\,$ (*why?*), but $a_n$ itself is not convegent.